# The $n^{th}$ digits of $e+\pi$ and a periodic sequence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, oeis

Let $n$ be a positive integer greater than zero. I denote the $n^{th}$ digits of $e$ and $\pi$ by $e_n$ and $\pi_n$ respectively. Let $d(e_n+\pi_n)$ count the number of divisors of $e_n+\pi_n$ and set $$\alpha(n)=gcd\big(n,2^{d(e_n+\pi_n)}\big)$$

> I want to prove and believe it to be true that $\alpha(n)$ is periodic with period $[1,2,1,4,1,2,1,8,1,2,1,4,1,2,1,16]$

I have verified the first 50 terms of $\alpha(n)$. A counter example would be nice.  This is pure curiosity.

Comment: Very interesting. But could you explain more why you believe this to be true? (personally, I don't, it seems quite unlikely, but if it is, well done). Also, didn't you forget a "$,$" in your sequence? I see a $14$ in it.

Comment: ^Term corrected.

Comment: do you consider $3$ in $\pi$ to be the first or zeroth digit?

Comment: @Vincent It doesn't matter much as long as you're doing the same thing to $e$, does it?

Comment: I think you should write a program that verifies this for large $n$. Since the computations involved are not very demanding, you should be able to check it easily for $n$ up to several million.

Comment: It is highly unlikely... if you had $gcd(n,2^r)$ where $r$ is a random positive integer, you are likely to get the same pattern.  As long as $n$ happens to equal $2^k$ and $r<k$ that the pattern is going to break, and in the first 50 members of the sequence digits, that is pretty likely.

Comment: A conceptual (theoretical) explanation of why this idea will eventually turn out to be wrong, is the fact that your conjecture is relying on decimal base (i.e., base-$10$), which has "nothing special" in the given context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sequence is simply the largest power of $2$ dividing into $n$ up to $16$.  It will fail when $e_n+\pi_n$ is prime and $n$ has a divisor of $8$ or $16$.  It will also fail when $e_n+\pi_n=12$, which has $6$ factors, and $n$ is divisible by $32$.  It will also fail when $e_n= \pi_n=0$ and $n$ is even.  You just haven't looked far enough.

If you start counting with $e_1=7$, the digit behind the decimal point, your claim fails at $n=8$.  We have $e_8=2, \pi_8=5,d(7)=2, \gcd=4$, not $8$ per your post.  Please check your calculations.  With the clarification that $n=1$ is the digit before the decimal point, it *still* fails at $n=32$.  We have $e_{32}=6, \pi_{32}=5,d(11)=2, \gcd=4$, not $8$ per your post.

Comment: Just so that's said: Without checking, there's no  guarantee that any of those things will ever happen. The probability that it happens _somewhere_ (assuming the digits of $\pi$ and $e$ are more or less random if you go far enough out) is $1$, but if it turns out to just never happen, proving that it never happens will probably be _extremely_ difficult.

Comment: @ross Do we know that the above conditions you state will exist in the digits of $e$ and $\pi$.

Comment: @AnthonyHernandez:  as Arthur says, we are "sure" that all of them will because the digits of $e$ and $\pi$ are random.  It is very difficult to prove it in general, but these will be easy to find.  The last case should happen once in $200$ digits.  The first one should happen about once in $24$ tries-the chance that the sum is prime is about $1/3$ and the chance $n$ is divisible by $8$ is $1/8$, so if your code is correct you have been unlucky to not see one already..

Comment: @RossMillikan we start at $e=2.7...$ and $\pi=3.1..$

Comment: Did you mean to say that $e_1=2$?  You should have been explicit, first in the post, then especially in the last comment.  I think it is perverse to say that as it would be normal to consider the first number behind the decimal point $1$, but if that is what you want to say you should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but the reason why I believed it is true is based on the observation that of $n$ is odd then $\alpha(n)=1$. In fact we appear to have the following

- $\alpha(n)=1$ if $n$ is odd
- $\alpha(n)=2$ if $n=4k+2$
- $\alpha(n)=4$ if $n=8k+4$
- $\alpha(n)=8$ if $n=16k+8$
- $\alpha(n)=16$ if $n=16k$

This appears to be true for the first $50$ terms. That lead me to believe there was some structure here.

Comment: This is a true statement of the structure of your sequence.  It is just the greatest power of $2$ dividing $n$ up to $16$.  Your claim fails when $2^{d(e_n+\pi_n)}$ is less than this.

Answer (score 0):

@rossmilman

You are correct, my claim is false. It holds only for the first 31 terms - where I had a hand written error. My bad ! I ran a code that calculated $\alpha(n)$ for the first $500\text{ }000$ digits of $e$ and $\pi$ and surely $\alpha(n)$ is never periodic ! I got the terms for $e$ and $\pi$ from NASA.